Substitute for SslCaCertificateStores in confluent kafka for dockerised applications
SslCaCertificateStores property doesn't support ubuntu.It works fine on windows
EXCEPTION=System.ArgumentException: Configuration property "ssl.ca.certificate.stores"
not supported in this build: configuration only valid on Windows
Now we are dockerising the application which reads and writes to confluent kafka topics.
what should be the replacement for SslCaCertificateStores property in consumerConfig method.
tried SslCaLocation property but not sure what should be the value for it. getting certificate issues around it.
Image created should work without any errors
